# Why am I getting an "Upload Failed" error?

Tags: geometry-dash

I always wanted to upload many of my levels, however, I seem to get this message every time I try to do so:
[image: Upload Failed. Please try again later.]

Then, the "later" part seems to be more than 3 years.

I got a comment on my last one talking about this error saying to sign up for an account. but, I cannot sign in after I create the account.

Comment: Next time, we'd prefer if you edit your old question to provide updated information instead of deleting and reposting it. By choosing to delete and repost your problem, you've basically removed all the history of the question, such as whether it was closed or reopened.

Comment: To include a photo correctly, you place the `[![description][1]][1]` at the location you want to have the photo. The line that is `[1]: https://photo.ca` should go at the *end* of your post.

Comment: Usually when I've gotten this error the servers are down. This is probably not the issue, and it doesn't make sense that you can't log in to your account. **Are you logged in? If so, *Save* your account, *Unlink* your account, *Log In* again, then *Load* your account.** You will get a warning saying all saved data will be deleted. It will not be if you *save* your account first, so **be sure to save. ONCE YOU LOG IN DO NOT SAVE YOUR ACCOUNT UNTIL YOU HAVE LOADED IT, THIS WILL OVERWRITE THE PREVIOUS SAVE.**